# Instalar emulador Nesbox no Wordpress 2

Tags: shortcode, nesbox, plugin-wordpress

Estou com dúvida em relação ao modo como o foi códido usado para criar o shortcode e a forma que é gerado o HTML. Acompanhei todo o desenvolvimento no post com a dúvida sobre como [Instalar emulador Nesbox no Wordpress](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91673/201), inclusive a conversa no chat. Mas faltam códigos e há conclusões subentendidas. Então, alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda com isto, falta pouco agora.

- Eu consigo fazer rodar o emulador em uma página separada HTML pura e criei o plugin conforme o exemplo, porém quando ativo o plugin dá um erro fatal no Wordpress:

> "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter -
>   headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/tipsg762/public_html/snesoline/wp-content/plugins/arcadetom/arcadetom.php:36)
>   in
>   /home/tipsg762/public_html/snesoline/wp-content/themes/arcade-pulse/functions.php
>   on line 1438"

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Alguma sugestão @brasofilo ?

Comment: @Endou como você resolveu?